# What is the difference between `Array` and `Array()`?

Tags: vba, excel, variable-declaration

I could declare an array thus:

```
Dim arrTest() As Variant
```

or thus:

```
Dim arrTest2 As Variant
arrTest2 = Array()
```

however, the first can only be passed as an argument like this:

```
Sub(ByRef arrTest() As Variant)
```

and the second like this:

```
Sub(ByRef arrTest2 As Variant)
```

you can do this with the second:

```
ReDim arrTest2(UBound(arrTest2) + N)
```

but not with the first.

What is the difference between a variable array declared the first way, and a variable array declared the second?
 They're both the same `vartype() - 8204 - Array of variants`
 Why do macros treat them differently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first is an array of variants. It is *always* an array -- it can't be reassigned to be e.g. a Range. The second is a variant which can hold just about anything, including an array (which it does in this case). Consider the following code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim arrTest() As Variant
    Dim arrTest2 As Variant
    arrTest2 = Array()
    Debug.Print "arrTest is a " & TypeName(arrTest)
    Debug.Print "arrTest2 is a " & TypeName(arrTest2)
End Sub
```

When you run it, you get this:

```
arrTest is a Variant()
arrTest2 is a Variant()
```

Which is what strikes you as strange. If they are the same type why does VBA sometimes treat them as different?

Answer -- they *aren't* the same type! `typename` (or just `varType`), when applied to a variant variable *doesn't* return the variables type at all. Instead it returns the *subtype* of the variable (a concept that only makes sense for variants). To get a clearer picture of what is happening -- put a break point before the first `Debug.Print` statement, run it, and open up the `Locals Window`:

[image]

Note how the type of `arrTest` is `Variant()` but `arrTest2` is `Variant/Variant(0 to -1)`. They really aren't the same type. `arrTest` is an array so it has to follow VBA syntax regarding array. `arrTest2` isn't an array at all -- it is simple variable (of type variant) so it follows the VBA syntax of simple (non-array) variables. The fact that in this particular case it is pointing to an array doesn't make it an array variable.

If you are familiar with C, your question is similar to the question that many beginning C programmers ask about the difference between `int` and `int*`, only in some ways it is more mysterious here since the fact that functions like `varType` and `TypeName` implicitly dereference any variant variable is arguably a design flaw. In some way it would be nice if `typename(arrTest2)` would return the more accurate (albeit more verbose) `Variant/Variant()` in this case.

Comment: *The second is a variant which can hold just about anything...* Yep, they've even added support for storing a UDT variable within a variant now. One type that still CANNOT be stored in a variant is the Fixed-Length String.

Comment: @ExcelHero Interesting -- I didn't know that there was anything that a variant couldn't refer to.